# Best way to perform a SELECT statement and insert into the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to improve the following statements:

```
insert into ProductInfo with (rowlock) (orderid, productname)
      select 66673, FileInfoId
        from ProductInfo with (nolock) where 
          ProductId = 66671 and
          IsEligableForCopy = 1 and 
          ProductFileInfoId >= 2768395941 and 
          ProductFileInfoId < 2768405941
```

Comment: What problem are you having with it?  Does it fail?  Does it run too slowly?  Does it create too many locks?  Does it report errors?

Comment: It will sometimes return a time out query.

Comment: @Salil - Not sure that reformatting was necessary. I preferred Mark's version! @RPS - What indexes do you have on `ProductInfo`? And how many records will the Select return?

Comment: You should run an explain plan on your query, to find out the bottleneck

Comment: Maybe I need to add an index on ProductFileInfoId? This table has about 40million records.

Comment: @RPS - What indexes do you have on ProductInfo? And how many records will the Select return? Also when you post SQL questions can you use code formatting and tag with RDBMS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is timing out because it fails to obtain a lock.  What DBMS are you using?  And have you tried it without requesting a lock?  The example you present appears to be a one-time insert, but I assume this is just an example, as opposed to something you would run in production.

Comment: I am using SQL 2005, maybe I should be removing the rowlock and nolock?

Comment: I would think that the locks should be unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I will try with removing the rowlock and nolock and see if it improves.

Thanks!

Comment: @RPS I don't understand why you asked this question then failed to respond when asked about existing indexes and number of records. (Both highly relevant to the performance of your query)

Comment: @Martin Sorry I missed that post,

It will return 10000 rows at a time, and I don't have an index on ProductFileInfoId... Maybe that will help!

Comment: Also, I know there is never updates happening on the ProductFileInfo table so that is the reason for NOLOCK.. Only inserts.

Comment: @RPS - What is the clustered index on the table?

Comment: @RPS If it is the SELECT that is taking a long time then a composite index on ProductId, IsEligableForCopy, ProductFileInfoId might help with included column FileInfoId

Comment: ProductId is the clustered index on the table.

Comment: @RPS and will your insert end up putting it at the end (e.g. are you always inserting the `Max(ProductId) + 1`?

Comment: @RPS In any event you're probably best off optimising the performance of the `SELECT` part first by providing appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Improve or add indicies on ProductInfo...maybe it won't timeout

Answer (score 0):

The Query looks fine. It should be running perfectly. Is there anything specific that you want to achieve.?